# Error in turtlebot_simulator at gazebo_ros_create

Tags: python, simulation, turtlebot, gazebo-plugins, turtlebot-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run the turtlebot_simulator on Ubuntu Precise with Fuerte, which used to work, but now Gazebo crashes with this error:

Service call failed: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

In the log spawn_turtlebot_model-4.log I get:

[rospy.internal][WARNING] 2012-06-15 11:53:02,280: Unknown error initiating TCP/IP socket to ivan-MacBookPro:58025 (http://ivan-MacBookPro:39830/): Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 511, in connect
self.socket.connect((dest_addr, dest_port))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

I commented the Gazebo plugin startup of gazebo_ros_create in turtlebot_description/urdf/turtlebot_body.urdf.macro

!--turtlebot_sim_create/--

and now the robot can spawn.

Any idea of what is happening?

EDIT:
I still have this problem with the latest updates and it also happens on Ubuntu 11.10 and (also) Fuerte.

Obviously commenting out the create plugin for gazebo is not really a solution, since I lose the odometry, etc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36571/error-in-turtlebot_simulator-at-gazebo_ros_create/) by [zorianovixh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2503/zorianovixh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-06-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was having a similar issue and found that I could "resolve" it with the answer to this post:

http://answers.ros.org/question/38465/fuerte-turtlebot-simulator-ubuntu-1204-precise/

It does seem, again, like a temporary solution but I think you can get the odometry back in the meanwhile.

---

Originally posted by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) with karma: 549 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0